# find prime number of diffie-hellman algorithm

Tags: diffie-hellman, ipsec

at IPsec, Diffie-hellman is used in framework ISAKMP resulting shared secret. some of Diffie-Hellman group may define the length of the prime number of q and the size of the secret key of K: group 1 (768 bit),Group 2 (1024 bit), atau Group 5 (1536 bit).

a. what is the prime number of group 1 at decimal and hexadecimal
b. what is the maximum length primitive root of q in decimal?

[image: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange]

Comment: A possible duplicate [What Diffie-Hellman parameters should I use?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29926/18298)

Comment: If you're asking what the group parameters that IKE uses, group 1, 2 is listed in sections 6.1, 6.2 of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2409 and group 5 is listed in section 2 of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3526/ .  BTW: in all three cases, the value 'a' (the generator) is not a primitive root.  In addition, nowadways all three groups is considered too small; we generally advise to use group 14 or bigger, or an elliptic curve group

Comment: why the value of 'a' is not a primitive root?

Comment: @LeeHyeWon: because they deliberately selected a value that was a Quadratic Residue, and QRs are never primitive roots